# Error while building a Char driver in fedora : /lib/modules/4.1.6-100.fc21.x86_64/build: No such file or directory. Stop

Tags: linux, fedora

While building a char driver I was getting bellow error:

```
 /lib/modules/4.1.6-100.fc21.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

I know this is because `Linux` headers are missing, so I tried below command in `fedora 21`.

```
#yum install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

And after doing this it says there no package available.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks
No package linux-headers-4.1.6-100.fc21.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can get around with this ?

Comment: Fedora 21 is EOL and the packages are not available in mirrors anymore. You should update to some recent version.

Answer (score 0):

---

In Fedora the package kernel-headers contains headers for /usr/include/*/*. No package by name linux-headers is available.

The headers for "kernel module build" is in the package kernel-devel : `dnf install kernel kernel-devel` ... I.e. the kernel version in use (`uname -r`) must be an exact match with the kernel-devel version.

---